# FieldError: Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'userinfo'. Choices are: userinfo

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I get this error when trying to use `only` with `select_related`.

```
FieldError: Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'userinfo'. Choices are: userinfo
```

It's a little strange that it reports the field I'm trying to select as an error.  Here is my query:

```
users_with_schools = User.objects.select_related('userinfo').only(
    "id",
    "date_joined",
    "userinfo__last_coordinates_id",
    "userinfo__school_id"
).filter(
    userinfo__school_id__isnull=False,
    date_joined__gte=start_date
)
```

I've been able to use `select_related` with `only` in other places in my code so I am not sure why this is happening.

Edit: Here is the full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 138, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 162, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 965, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 238, in iterator
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 818, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 367, in as_sql
    extra_select, order_by, group_by = self.pre_sql_setup()
  File "env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 48, in pre_sql_setup
    self.setup_query()
  File "env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 39, in setup_query
    self.select, self.klass_info, self.annotation_col_map = self.get_select()
  File "env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 203, in get_select
    related_klass_infos = self.get_related_selections(select)
  File "env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 743, in get_related_selections
    ', '.join(_get_field_choices()) or '(none)',
FieldError: Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'userinfo'. Choices are: userinfo
```

Comment: Would you mind to include your models on your question please?

Comment: Could you please post the models, especially the target FK `userinfo`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.only):

> All of the cautions in the note for the `defer()` documentation apply to `only()` as well. Use it cautiously and only after exhausting your other options.
>
> ...
>
> Using `only()` and omitting a field requested using `select_related()` is an error as well.

`select_related` will try to fetch *all* the columns for `userinfo`. As described above, trying to restrict the set of columns to specific ones will result in an error - the combination of `select_related` and `only` does not support that.

It's probably worth noting the comment that goes with these methods:

> The `defer()` method (and its cousin, `only()`, below) are only for advanced use-cases. They provide an optimization for when you have analyzed your queries closely and understand exactly what information you need and have measured that the difference between returning the fields you need and the full set of fields for the model will be significant.

**Edit**: you mention in a comment below that the following query, used elsewhere in your code, seems to work fine:

```
ChatUser.objects.select_related("user__userinfo").\
    only( "id", "chat_id", "user__id", "user__username", "user__userinfo__id" )
```

My best guess is that you are hitting [this bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24687) in Django ([fixed in 1.10](https://github.com/django/django/pull/5421)).

I suppose the easiest way to verify is to check the SQL query generated by the queryset that seems to work. My guess is that you will find that it isn't actually querying everything in one go and that there are additional queries when you try to access the related model that you asked to be fetched in `select_related`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  In another place I have:
chatusers_with_info = ChatUser.objects.select_related("user__userinfo").only(
        "id",
        "chat_id",
        "user__id",
        "user__username",
        "user__userinfo__id"
    )

And this works ok.  So my question is why one works and the other does not as they seem to be the same to me.

Comment: It could have something to do with the fact primary keys can't be deferred. Anyway the error message in your reported case should be improved. Could you try replacing `'user__userinfo__id'` by `'user__userinfo__school_id'` and see if you get a similar exception?

Comment: @EricConner I have edited my answer with a possible explanation for this contradictory behaviour.